# Validate datalist against database then prevent form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to get a form to work where the user will enter in a required value for a color that is shown via a datalist. If they have not submitted the right word, then I want my form to not submit. I have tried this for multiple hours but the closest that I can get right now is just making the elements required to be entered.

Here are my required inputs:

```
<label for="one">Width of chessboard:</label> <input id="one" type="text" name="width" value="<?php $width;?>" pattern="[0-9]{2,4}" title="Numbers, min 2 digits max 4 digits"> 
    <span class="error" id="widthp">* </span> <br>
<input name="col1" type="text" id="five" value="<?php $col1; ?>" list="col1" pattern="[a-z]{1,10}" title="Lowercase, max 10 chars" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter in a color from the dropdown')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
        <datalist id="col1" name="col1">
            <!-- options for colour 1 -->
            <option value="red">
            <option value="green">
            <option value="light blue">
            <option value="black">
            <option value="white">
            <option value="grey">
            <option value="brown">
            <option value="pink">
        </datalist>   
    <span class="error" id="col1p">* </span> <br> 
    <label for="six">Color 2:</label> 
    <!-- input for colour 2 -->
    <input name="col2" type="text" id="six" value="<?php $col2; ?>" list="col2" pattern="[a-z\s]{1,12}" title="Lowercase, max 12 chars" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter in a color from the dropdown')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
            <datalist id="col2" name="col2">
                <!-- options for colour 2 -->
                <option value="orange">
                <option value="dark green">
                <option value="dark blue">
                <option value="black">
                <option value="white">
                <option value="purple">
                <option value="yellow">
            </datalist>         
        <span class="error" id="col2p">* </span> <br>
```

And here is what I have been able to validate so far:

```
function validateForm() {
  var width = document.forms["chessboardForm"]["width"].value; // get the value of width
  if (width == "") { // check if it is empty
    // if it is then change message and display false
    document.getElementById("widthp").innerHTML = "* \'Width of chessboard\' must be filled out with the following values: Numbers, max 4 digits";
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: i don't see where you are calling the `validateForm()` function

Comment: That is called at the start of the form, I only included what I thought was necessary for the question.

Comment: `form` tag as a `submit` or `onsubmit` event, implement the event and validate your form, inside the function, if the validation fails, `return false` or just don't return anything for successful validation. In this case, call the `validateForm()` function inside `onsubmit` event function and you should be okay